# PDF reference links when using hyperref and (`ruled`) algorithm2e

Tags: hyperref, captions, algorithms, algorithm2e

I was testing some links within my produced PDF file and recognized that all of the links to an algorithm (from the `algorithm2e` package) will jump to the beginning of the algorithm with skipping half of the algorithm's header and the caption of the algorithm. I use the `ruled` option of the `algorithm2e` package such that the caption will be above the actual algorithm.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}
   Der Algorithmus \ref{alg:roundoff} approximiert das ''Closest Vector Problem``. 
   \newpage
       \begin{algorithm}
        \caption{\label{alg:roundoff}Babais \textsf{ROUNDING OFF-PROCEDURE}}

        \emph{Berechne $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n \in R$, sodass $\vec{q} = r_1\vec{b}_1+r_2\vec{b}_2+\cdots+r_n\vec{b}_n$ gilt.}\\
        $\vec{v} := \vec{0}$\\
        \For{$i = 1,2,\ldots,n$}
        {
            $\vec{v} := \vec{v} + \lfloor r_i\rceil \cdot \vec{b}_i$
        }
     \end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

This code will produce a (blue) link on the first page to the algorithm on the second page. But when zoomed and after clicking the link, it will jump to the following part of the algorithm:

[image: Wrong jump target on ruled algorithm]

Question: Is it possible to adjust the jump position for algorithms (from package `algorithm2e`) such that a click will jump to the position before the algorithm header/caption even if the `ruled` option of the `algorithm2e` package is used?

Comment: I already tried this (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146369/equivalent-to-hypcap-for-ruledalgorithm2e) but this is not working for the above example

Comment: I am using `latex + latex + dvips + ps2pdf`

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the `ruled` style, the caption is always placed on the top. As such, we can patch the start of the `algorithm` environment and insert the aid provided by [Equivalent to `hypcap` for `[ruled]{algorithm2e}`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/146369/5764).

The following patch is provided by [`xpatch`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xpatch), since the definition of `algorithm` takes an optional argument:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script

\usepackage[ruled]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}% http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref
\usepackage{hypcap,xpatch}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{hypcap,xpatch}
\makeatletter
% \xpatch{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\xpatchcmd{\algorithm}{\ignorespaces}{\ignorespaces%
  \smash{\raisebox{1.5\baselineskip}{\capstart}}}{}{}
% Insert \capstart immediately after algorithm environment starts
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Der Algorithmus \ref{alg:roundoff} approximiert das ''Closest Vector Problem``. 
\newpage
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{\label{alg:roundoff}Babais \textsf{ROUNDING OFF-PROCEDURE}}
  \emph{Berechne $r_1, r_2, \ldots, r_n \in R$, sodass $\vec{q} = r_1\vec{b}_1+r_2\vec{b}_2+\cdots+r_n\vec{b}_n$ gilt.}\\
  $\vec{v} := \vec{0}$\\
  \For{$i = 1,2,\ldots,n$}
  {
    $\vec{v} := \vec{v} + \lfloor r_i\rceil \cdot \vec{b}_i$
  }
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

All cases should be covered where the algorithm name does not span multiple lines. One drawback is the placement of dual hypertargets, leading to "destination with same identifier" [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref)/pdfTeX warning.

Comment: This is only working for `pdfLatex`. Is it normal that this won't work with `latex + latex + dvips + ps2pdf`?

Comment: I now just changed to `pdflatex` which works with this fix.